# non-sequential sequence function

Tags: special-functions, numerical-linear-algebra

if i remember correctly (*i had one workshop on numerics years ago, sorry for my lack of knowledge*) there is a way to create some sort of hash function that gives you a non sequential sequence.
This would create a table like:

```
| x | fn(x) |
| 1 |     4 |
| 2 |     6 |
| 3 |     1 |
| 4 |     5 |
| 5 |     2 |
| 6 |     3 |
```

Is it possible to create such a function with relatively simple math?

To give an insight into "what is it this guy need": I have a system that internally uses an incremental id (starts with 0, ends with n) and i want it to generate a random id (public id) from that.
This random id thou should not be higher than n because the id's should be kept small in the start.
The generated id would have not only numbers but also characters a-z.
So with having 4 digits for the public id, n would be ( 10 + 26 )^4 => 1679616 right?
So i need that function to work for n to m where n is 0 and m is 1679616.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the term "hash" means that you want your sequence to be essentially random, ideally without duplicates. So it looks like you want your "random" sequence to be a random permutation of 1 to n.  The best way to do this would be to get random bits, say by using the least significant digit of a measurement like wind speed or temperature. Pseudo-random number generators can also do what you want: If you have a pseudo-random number generator that can generate numbers between 1 and a large number N (you can multiply pairs or triplets of values to get up to large N), then you use this as a black box to generate a random number between 1 and n, and then generate a random number between 1 and n-1, etc., to get indices for swaps to generate a (pseudo)-random permutation that is your function to define your sequence. One of the earliest pseudo-random number generators was the linear congruential generator http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator which is easy to understand mathematically, but the Mersenne twister is much better and is what's used in many programming languages today.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are $n$ numbers in your sequence ($n=6$ in your example).  Choose some positive integer $a$ such that [gcd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor)$(a,n)=1$.  Then we define $$f(x)=ax\pmod{n}$$

This uses a term from [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic); what it means is that $f(x)$ is the remainder when we divide $ax$ by $n$.

The reason you want gcd$(a,n)=1$ is to avoid collisions; if $a,n$ had a common factor there would be several $x$'s that get sent to the same place.  Another benefit of this condition is that there must be another integer $b$ such that $ab\equiv 1\pmod{n}$.  This allows us to compute the inverse of $f(x)$ via $$g(x)=bx\pmod{n}$$
These are inverses, i.e. $g(f(x))=x$.  Hence given an element of the range of $f(x)$, we can compute which $x$ got sent there.

Comment: Your answer is very well written and would have helped me to find my solution if i hadn't found it in the other answer anyway. So i accepted the other answer and could only upvote yours. Still thou i want to say thank you for that amazing answer.